# Python elif works in IDLE but not Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm a Python newbie, currently working on my first project.

My elif statements seem to work in IDLE but not VSC

To demonstrate, I have a very simple if statement:

```
dud = 'You'
if dud == 'You':
    print('You got the dud!')
elif dud == 'Me':
    print('ohhhh, I made myself sad')
else:
    pass
```

When I submit this code to IDLE, it works no problem.
However, when I copy paste the exact same code into VSC and run in Python Terminal I get the following errors:

```
PS C:\Users\William> & C:/Users/William/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dud = 'You'
>>> 
>>> if dud == 'you':
...     print('You got the dud!')
...
>>> elif dud == 'Me':
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    elif dud == 'Me':
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>     print('ohhhh, I made myself sad')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print('ohhhh, I made myself sad')
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> else:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    else:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>     pass
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pass
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
```

Naturally, I've tried various different types of formatting but I can't get it to work. If I remove the elif section it works fine, so I feel like I must be missing something basic.

Any help would be greatly apprecaited!

edit: Increasingly odd behaviour leads me to believe that this is somehow a Visual Studio issue:

> Running code in 'Python interactive window" = Successful Fresh Launch
>   of VSC and using 'Run python file in terminal' = Succesful 'Run
>   selection/line in terminal' = Error encountered above Running 'Run
>   python file in terminal' after terminal has already running = error
>   encountered above

edit: People are rightly pointing out that that it looks like VSC is saying that there is an extra line being added.
I don't think that is the case: here's a screenshot of the code in VSC

[image: Description]

Comment: You have an extra newline after the `print('You got the dud!')` - that is causing the python terminal to end the if-statement. So your `elif` is getting a syntax error.

Comment: I believe it is copy/paste issue. So, try to edit the code in Visual Studio, use backspace key and enter...

Comment: Beside the point, but where's the output? You should see `You got the dud!` printed right after the second `...`. Also FWIW the `else` clause is irrelevant. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Hi all! VSC code here:https://imgur.com/a/FGxAKZD

Comment: if you have a `.py` file you don't copy/paste that in to the Python terminal. You start the debugger or the python interpreter via a launch. See the VSC debug page on how to setup `launch.json`

Comment: Don't see where is the problem. I copy-pasted the code on my VS Code and it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the terminal snippet and screenshot, what VSC is actually running is equivalent to this:

```
dud = 'You'

if dud == 'You':
    print('You got the dud!')

elif dud == 'Me':
    print('ohhhh, I made myself sad')
else:
    pass
```

The problem is that second line break after `print('You got the dud!')`. It's making Python think that the if-statement is all done, so when it sees the `elif` and everything that follows, it errors.

The source of the problem isn't clear though.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct but I'm not sure why it's interpreting it this way. I have a screenshot here of the code being submitted: https://imgur.com/a/FGxAKZD
Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: @William Huh, yeah the screenshot looks good. I don't normally use VSC but I just tried to reproduce the issue but couldn't.

Comment: Interesting! I just tried it on a different computere and it was replicated there.

Answer (score 0):

Notice...

```
 >>> elif
```

You've started a new statement and ended the if statement

`elif <conditional>` on its own is invalid, and each following line therefore is being interpreted on its own.

I suggest using IPython rather than the regular python REPL, or use JupyterLab

Comment: Thanks Cricket.
Yes, I see from the outpute that's how the code is being interpretered. However, i'm not sure why it's being interpreted that way based on the code itself. Please see the screenshot at the bottom of the post for details.

Comment: What python plugin are you using? The vs-code code **should be** interpreted as whole, as a script, not line by line like the REPL. If you've pasted or typed, you must pay attention to the left column indicating continue or new statements

Comment: Just 'Python' and 'Jupyter'. I believe that must somehow be related to something in VS code, as copy pasting the code into python webbrowsers seems to work fine.

Comment: I've just edited the post to expand upon how the code sometimes runs and sometimes doesn't. I think it must be something in VSC but not sure what.

Comment: I suggest reporting your issue as a bug to the Python plugin maintainers, then. Also notice that the print statement in your screenshot has a red sgwiggle under it... I think you should open that file in a hex editor because there's clearly some hidden whitespace characters in there

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will submit as a bug.

Comment: @WilliamO'Connor I'm seeing what I believe is the same issue, did you open a bug on this?